# PhoneGap support latest version of iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cordova

Is PhoneGap always support new version of iPhone?

or we have to do some settings to run application on latest iphone version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always run a backward compatible app on a new iOS version. (above 3.0 that is) Its the minimum supported iOS that you can set in settings (again above 3.0 only)
And phonegap supports all iOS versions (above 3.0 again, dont know about lower versions)

Comment: yes, phonegap suppred by apple : http://blogs.nitobi.com/brian/2009/10/07/phonegap-0-8-0-is-apple-approved/

Comment: Starting with 2.0 version it supports only ios 4.2+ devices

Comment: This question was asked 2 years ago, when 2.0 dint exist. And even with that, the answer remains that the new versions of iOS are always supported. So strange you would go ahead and down vote on this stale question!!

Answer (score -1):

yes, phonegap suppred by apple : http://blogs.nitobi.com/brian/2009/10/07/phonegap-0-8-0-is-apple-approved/